# Translating Highcharts using ng2-translate

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts, ng2-translate

I'm trying to translate Highcharts' name series using [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) with Angular 2 RC.6.

I have the chart configuration in my constructor, where I call a function to translate the series name:

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {  
  this.config = {
    series: [{ name: this.getTranslation('TRANSLATETHIS') }
  }
}
```

Inside that function, I call the `TranslationService`:

```
getTranslation(word) {
  this.translate.get(word).subscribe((res: string) => {
    return res;
  })
}
```

I managed to log the right translation into the console. However, Highcharts keep showing `Series 1` instead of the translated word.

If I use the `TranslateService` inside the constructor (without a function), it works, though.

However, I have to translate other things, so it would be handy using a function instead of repeating the service for every word.

Comment: My guess is that this is a JavaScript async race condition.  The `get` call above is *async*, so your `getTranslation` is returning after highcharts does it's thing.  If you are **certain** that your translations have already loaded, you should be using `instant`.

Comment: If you want to change a chart dynamically, like series name, you could update a series using [Series.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.update).